# Angular Scope Not Printing Variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-service, angular-controller

I have an angular factory and controller as such:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource'])
.factory('Widget', ['$http', function WidgetFactory($http) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            return $http({method: "GET", url: "/widgets"});
        }
    };
}])
.controller('StoreCtrl', ['$scope', 'Widget', function($scope, Widget) {
    $scope.widgets = Widget.all();
}]);
```

In my front-end I have

```
<div ng-controller="StoreCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
        {{ widget.price }}
        {{ widget.name }}
    </li>
</div>
```

But nothing gets populated in my `{{ widget.price }}` and etc.
**What am I missing?**

Comment: print $scope.widgets in your controllers check whether it contains data or not

Comment: your can see your data if data is available by using this line console.log($scope.widgets);
or use debugging mode in your browser.

Comment: There is data available. It's an array of objects. But the objects properties do not appear in their `{{ widget.name }}` in the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: its not a good practice but for now instead of $scope use $rootScope and try.

Comment: @VishalSingh that breaks it completely.

Comment: try to use service if it is not working for the same

Comment: What? That's not even a sentence.

Comment: create service like this .service('WidgetService', function() {
  var myList = []; 
  var addList = function(newObj) { myList.push(newObj); } 
  var getList = function(){ return myList; } 
  return { addList: addList, getList: getList }; 
})

Comment: why cant you update your exact json structure sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not quite resolving your promise as the framework expects. Check out the [$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for some explanation on promises. We also need to set our view model value (scope) to the correct returned value from [the response object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage), composed of the following...

> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
> - transform functions. status – {number} – HTTP status code of the
> - response. headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
> - the request. statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Observe the following...

```
Widget.all().then(function (response) {
    $scope.widgets = response.data;
});
```

Furthermore, as a few observations, there is no need to name your factory function as you did with `WidgetFactory`, an anonymous function will do. You can also leverage the [$http shortcut method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods) `get` as well as such...

```
.factory('Widget', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            return $http.get('/widgets');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

$http returns a promise. You need to assign the response data to $scope.widgets when the promise resolves. In the controller, try this:

```
Widget.all().then(function (data) {
    $scope.widgets = data;
});
```

Comment: So I got the same result. But I can't access the values inside of `widgets` when I `ng-repeat="widget in widgets"` and do `{{ widget.name }}`

Comment: Have you verified that the call to /widgets is returning anything?

Comment: Could you log the response data and see its value in console?

Comment: Yes, I've verified the call to `/widgets` returns JSON objects. The `<li>` repeats 1 less many times than there are objects returned by the `/widgets` call. I made the change @varun suggested and after I call `$scope.widgets = data;` I call `console.log(data);` I get my data array of widgets.

Comment: Put $scope.$apply() after $scope.widgets = data.

Comment: Do you guys even know what you're talking about or are you just throwing a bunch of bullshit up here?

Comment: this seems to be the most helpful answer here, since you need to resolve a promise to get your results. There is no need to call `$apply`, since we're entirely in the context of angular with this code in question. @gh0st it sounds like you're missing something minor, is there a css class affecting one of the `<li>` elements or something to alter it's visibility?

Comment: Also for the sake of verbosity in your example above, perhaps assign your var to `data.data`. That's generally a bad param name for the callback, you'll typically see `response.data`, for there is usually a `data` property on the returned object

Comment: Not that I am aware. The `<li>` is repeated for `$scope.widgets.length - 1`. The part that's stumping me is that the repeat happens, data is sent and held in `$scope.widgets` but it won't display on the view.

Comment: @scniro the `$scope.widgets = data.data` did the trick. Thank you. Finally someone who knows what they're talking about. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it.

Comment: @gh0st hehe, cheers. Glad you got it solved. Haven't seen a question spiral this out of control in a while ;) I'd definitely go the `response.data` route as well

Comment: @gh0st for completeness I posted my answer, along with some minor suggestions

Comment: Before posting a question on stack overflow, you should know, what is the response you are getting from the web service. You said you are getting an array in response but it was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

**First make sure you have an objects of Array at**

```
  $scope.widgets;
```

**in your controller.**
you can print this line in your controller

```
console.log($scope.widgets);
```

to see if the data is available or not.

Comment: Can you see the data in controller ?